# Podcasts play in Reverse Order

Tags: ios

I regularly listen to Podcasts from a radio station. These normally consist of a number of segments, which I download as individuals.

On my old iPod (iOS6) these played in Music in order.
On my iPhone5S (iOS8) they play in Podcasts in reverse order (last played first), regardless of the order I download them. If I select the 1st (usually the last unplayed in the list), it does not automatically continue with the list, although if I play the last it does, but the segments are in reverse order.

Is there any way of making iPhone5S (iOS8) behave like iPod (iOS6)?
(There is a similar 3 year old question - I hoped Apple would have fixed this bug by now.)

Comment: In case anyone gets here because of trying to figure out how to fix this on MacOS iTunes, try this suggestion: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250527252  It was the only thing that worked for me (changing the "play oldest to newest" setting on the individual podcast did nothing).

Answer (score 3):

When you select the podcast, click on the description by the icon (at the top of the page above the Unplayed/Feed heading with an arrow that takes you to another page) and it'll give you some settings. These settings allow you to set the order in which they play.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out with Podbean if you click the all button to the right of the downloaded button the arrow is either going up or down  and that changes the order you can listen to the podcasts like it you want oldest first